# Where do I store development resources in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, resources

I have some raw resources that I need during development of my application.
Lets call it picture.svg, demoData.sql and largeFile.bin.

During development I use the svg image to (manually) generate the actual images that my application uses. The demoData.sql is mainly for gui demo (or manual testing) purposes. Something similar happens with the bin file. My IDE does not need them at all.

On one hand I would like to have all resources I need for my project in one common folder or at least somewhere safe in scm. On the other hand I consider these files as "sources", that should not be in the final jar by any chance.

As far as I can tell I have 5 choices what to do with them:

1. Throw them in their own project and let most developers forget that it exists (nasty overhead if there are only a few resources like that)
2. Throw them in the root folder and filling up the treeview of my project everytime I add a new resource (myProject/picture.svg)
3. Throw them in a folder outside of the maven structure and confuse future developers (myProject/resources/picture.svg)
4. Throw them in the src/main/resources folder and apply some filters to it, but this might cause issues due to eclipse/IDE just throwing everything together, if not using "clean package"
5. Throw them in a src/dev/resources or src/dev/sql folder to clarify when they are needed.

I found this maven reference: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html
but this only covers the actual resources and not some dev ones.

Is there a maven/coding standard where to put the dev resources?
IMO it should be #5 or #4.

Comment: Test resources should go to `myProject/src/test/resources/` directory.

Comment: @Boris They can be used for tests, but thats not their main purpose. Its mainly files that I need during development, but not after that.

Comment: Then another directory could be added `myProject/src/dev/resources/` to store those files. Add it to the resources manually in your IDE.

Comment: You could also opt for a multi modules Maven project and have your dev resources in the dev / tools module of your project, to exclude them from your artifact, but keep them close to your main. I quite like your fifth option though, as it feels similar than what is demonstrated by maven plugins such as maven-assembly-plugin or maven-jaxb2-plugin.